# PWC6188: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jstl

I am working on a dynamic web project in Eclipse Kepler. I am trying to write a simple JSP using JSTL `<c:forEach>`. For that I have included the required JAR `jstl-1.2.jar` under libraries and added the following statement to JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

However, when I run it using *Run as --> Run on Server*, it shows the following error.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /test.jsp(4,61) PWC6188: The absolute uri:     http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

I have already consulted a lot of links, but I don't understand how this is caused and how I can solve it.

Comment: where is the jar located? It must be in `WEB-INF/lib/`.

Comment: I have to add jar by going to project properties- Java build path --> Add external JAR. It automatically adds it in JAVA RESOURCES--> Libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *For that I have included the required JAR jstl-1.2.jar under libraries*

This makes it only available during compile time, not run time.

You need to **undo** everything which you did in project's *Build Path* and *Deployment Assembly* properties. If you're not sure anymore what changes you've all done over there, then throw away the current project and recreate the project from scratch and remember to never touch the project's *Build Path* and *Deployment Assembly* properties until you really really understand what it is doing under the covers (in other words, when you're able to create, build and deploy a WAR from top of head in command prompt without using any IDE).

The proper procedure is:

- Open the project's `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` folder.
- Drop the `jstl-1.2.jar` file in there.

That's it. Nothing more needs to be done. No need to fiddle anywhere in project's properties. Eclipse will automatically do the necessary magic there.

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

---

**Update**: as per the comments,

> *web.xml is declared to version 2.4 and I am using Basic Server: J2EE Preview at localhost*

There's the cause of your problem. JSTL 1.2 requires a minimum of Servlet 2.5 and "J2EE Preview" is completely outdated. Grab [Tomcat 7](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi#7.0.47) (pick the core ZIP file), extract it, integrate it in Eclipse, add the project to Tomcat, fix your `web.xml` to be Servlet 3.0 compatible, then start Tomcat and enter the desired URL in your favourite webbrowser.

Comment: I did not change any project properties, I only added this JAR file in Libraries (using ADD Jar Option in Eclipse).
I have also tried dropping the jar physcially into WEB-INF/lib and re-run the project but still the error persists.

Comment: As answered, that is **not** the right procedure. The proper procedure is already answered. Why do you keep trying to do it differently?

Comment: Then you've seriously messed up your project. As answered, recreate it from scratch and do not try to do things differently.

Comment: I don't think I have messed up my project because I did not touch any settings/properties. Moreover I just now tried your solution by creating a new Dynamic Web Project, I just created one JSP file to test, and dropped that jar in web-inf/lib, still does not works. The same error is coming.

Comment: What server exactly are you using and what version exactly is `web.xml` declared to? Did you read the JSTL wiki page carefully from top to bottom?

Comment: I have used JSTL before also and everytime I did it was easily able to configure it. I dont understand why is it not working now.  web.xml is declared to version 2.4
and I am using Basic Server: J2EE Preview at localhost.

Comment: There's the cause of the problem. It already ships with JSTL 1.0 out the box which uses a different taglib URI. Now go read the JSTL wiki page. It's mentioned over there as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. solved it now.. It uses URI that ends with core_rt.

Comment: I'd rather upgrade the project+server to the current versions. There's no point using dead technology.

Comment: Yes I have to do that. Actually this is a small module, once I move it to another server for integration, that time I will change it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `jstl-1.2.jar` is included in your `WEB-INF/lib` directory and the deployment assembly.

> 1. Right Click Project > Project Properties
> 2. Deployment Assembly
> 3. Click Add, then Folder
> 4. Select the WEB-INF/lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem and nothing straght forward about it online.

SOLUTION:
Add JSTL library to the project libraries